# How to fill all holes with shrinkwrap function?

Tags: shrinkwrap

I'm working for an architecture firm trying to clean up our Revit model and 3D print it.  I looked through the 3D checklist and tried to clean up the model but every time I "Make Manifold" blender deletes walls.

My friend uses Materialise Magics software which has this function called Shrinkwrap.  Essentially it covers the entire model with this blanket (which you can adjust to become more refined to show more detail) and plugs all holes.  Then he thickens the model and prints it.

Do you think blender has a similar feature? I know blender has the shrinkwrap tool but after messing around with it, it hasn't fixed the holes or thickness issues I am having.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would try to use fill the hole and then try to remesh it, voxel remesh or something like that to get rid of the non-manifold geometry

Comment: You could use the remesh modifier with a high enough octree depth and then use the sculpting  smooth tool if you notice an unwanted surface structure. The holes will be closed this way but I don't know if this is the most elegant and clean way to do this.